# A new theorem in projective geometry

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, projective-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> **My question:** I am looking for a proof of **problem** as following:

**Introduction:**  When I research a theorem as following:

**Theorem [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c8U0.png):**  Let $ABC$ be a triangle, let $(S)$ be a circumconic of $ABC$, let $P$ be a point on the  plane. Let the lines $AP, BP, CP$ meet the conic again at $A', B', C'$. Let $D$  be a point on the polar of point $P$ with respect to $(S)$ or $D$ lies on the conic $(S)$. Let $A_0= DA' \cap BC$, $B_0= DB' \cap AC$; $C_0= DC' \cap AB$. Then $A_0, B_0, C_0$  are collinear. Further more four points $A_0, B_0, C_0, P$ are collinear if only if $D$ lie on the conic.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c8U0.png)-[Nguyen Ngoc Giang, A proof of Dao theorem, Global Journal of Advanced Research on Classical and Modern Geometries, ISSN: 2284-5569, Vol.4, (2015), Issue 2, page 102-105](http://gjarcmg.geometry-math-journal.ro/)

[image]

I found a nice result adding to configuration of theorem 1 as following:

**Problem:**  *In the case D lies on the conic $(S)$. Let $AP$ meets $BC$ at $P_a$. Let the line  through $D$ and parallel to $AP$, this line meets $BC$ at $D_a$. Let $D'_a$ on the ray $DD_a$ such that $\frac{\overline{DD_a}}{\overline{DD'_a}}=\frac{\overline{A'P_a}}{\overline{A'P}}$. Define $D'_b, D'_c$ cyclically. Then seven points $A_0, B_0, C_0, D'_a, D'_b, D'_c$ and $P$ are collinear.*

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gn8O.png)-[The problem is the problem 11 in this paper](http://www.journal-1.eu/2016-3/Dao-Thanh-Oai-Generalizations-pp.12-20.pdf)

[image]

Comment: what is "nine points conic of P"? it would be more clear if you formulated this in terms of equations, than in geometric terms

Comment: I thank to You, please see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_conic

Comment: If you apply an affine transform and move (ABC, P) to a triangle and orthocenter will you get the regular Feuerbach theorem?

Comment: I thank to You very much dear @akopyan

Comment: I deleted old result. I keep new result.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, it is already known that $A_0,B_0,C_0$ and $P$ are collinear as stated in Theorem 1 above or proven [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/DoublePascalConic.shtml). Call this common line $L$. It remains to prove that $D_a',D_b'$ and $D_c'$ lie on $L$. For this, suppose that the ray $DD_a$ intersects $L$ at $D_a''$. Using similarities $\Delta A_0DD_a\sim \Delta A_0A'P_a$ and $\Delta A_0DD_a''\sim \Delta A_0A'P,$ one has $$\frac{\overline{DD_a}}{\overline{A'P_a}}=\frac{\overline{A_0D}}{\overline{A_0A'}}=\frac{\overline{DD_a''}}{\overline{A'P}}\Rightarrow\frac{\overline{DD_a}}{\overline{DD_a''}}=\frac{\overline{A'P_a}}{\overline{A'P}},$$which shows that $D_a''$ coincides with $D_a'$. This shows that $D_a'$ lies on $L$. Similarly (repeating the argument cyclically), $D_b'$ and $D_c'$ lie on $L$. Hence the seven points $A_0,B_0,C_0,D_a',D_b',D_c'$ and $P$ are collinear.

Comment: please check your email, or your junk email